# Haxe flash hardware optimization

Tags: flash, gpu, haxe, wmode

It is possible to enabled hardware optimization (wmode) from haxe?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It should be enabled from html page AFAIK.

```
<object  type="application/x-shockwave-flash" data="file.swf" >
    <param name="movie" value="file.swf">
    <param name="wmode" value="gpu">
</object>
```

Comment: Do you have any examples?

Comment: @62316e Added example